# Insight via Api

Tags: api, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, facebook-insights

I'm using the insight metrics via API.
But I don't have any results for all the post-related metrics:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/[page_id]/insights/post_stories
https://graph.facebook.com/[page_id]/insights/post_impressions
https://graph.facebook.com/[page_id]/insights/post_storytellers
```

and so on.
I try to use also FQL without any results.
While extracting these data via Insight panel in xls, I can read the value.
But I want them via API.
Someone can help me?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you have find an answer, but having done the same, I believe you must use the post id since each page post has each own stories created and impressions etc .

So , `https://graph.facebook.com/[page_post_id]/insights/post_stories` , would work.